# java keytool too long address

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, keystore

I am trying to generate a certificate using keytool with the following command:

```
keytool.exe -genkeypair -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -dname CN=www.some-thing.aaa.bbb.ccc.com -sigalg SHA1withRSA -validity 3650 -keystore D:\path\Path\keystore
```

The certificate gets generated and placed in the keystore. However after I open my browser it doesn't accept the certificate because the certificate has following properties:

issued to: *.aaa.bbb.ccc.com
issued by: *.aaa.bbb.ccc.com

The above is problematic because "*.aaa.bbb.ccc.com" is not equal to "www.some-thing.aaa.bbb.ccc.com " thus the certificate is not seen as issued by correct authority.

How do I generate a certificate so that it contains full address in "issued to" and "issued by"?

Thanks,
M.

Comment: Use `bouncycastle` (`org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator`) to create certificate

Comment: I don't think you've diagnosed this correctly. The problem is more likely that the certificate is self-signed, not that the wildcard doesn't match. You should post the actual error message in your question to elucidate this.

Comment: @EJP Chrome is actually giving me this error: "The server could not prove that it is  "www.some-thing.aaa.bbb.ccc.com" it's certificate is from "*.aaa.bbb.ccc.com". This may be caused by missconfiguration or an attacker intercepting connection"

Comment: A wildcard cert only works for one level, so your *.aaa.bbb.ccc.com cert is good for one.aaa.bbb.ccc.com and two.aaa.bbb.ccc.com but not wwww.three.aaa.bbb.ccc.com. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70882/how-many-hostnames-can-be-supported-by-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-is-there-any . I don't know what you mean by "full address"; the subject (issued to) is whatever you specify, and for selfsigned (as keytool generates by default) the issuer (issued by) is the same as subject.

Comment: So i managed to create a certificate with bouncy castle and the issued to and issued by values are fine but after i put it into a java keystore the issued to and issued by are altered back to short forms with wildcards. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Putting a cert into a keystore does not change it -- in fact nothing can change an issued cert because it is digitally signed exactly to prevent that. Did you use BC (and how) to create a *privatekey with cert* or just a cert, or did you create a cert and *add* it to a privatekey? Only a privatekey PLUS cert IN ONE ENTRY works for an SSL server. Do you have more than one privatekey entry in your keystore? If so the server might use the wrong one.

Comment: Also: make sure, if you haven't already, that you are modifying the same keystore the server is using, and the server is (re)started AFTER you modify the keystore.

Comment: @Margaret That's exactly what I said. 'Proof' implies a self-signed certificate problem. Get it signed by a CA.

Comment: @EJP For selfsigned not in truststore, Chrome says "server could not prove it is $host; its security certificate is not trusted by your computer[]". For selfsigned in truststore but wrong host, and also for signed-by-CA with CA in truststore but wrong host, Chrome says "server could not prove it is $host; its security certificate is from $other". Both of these say "prove" but only the second matches the OP's reported symptom.

Comment: My issue has been resolved.

It turned out that there is some kind of reverse proxy with a different certificate. Also Bouncy castle is a very good library to create self signed ones. Thank you for all your answers.